# What is wrong with these rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is wrong with this code, I thought it was working but it appears not to be now, any help?

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum.ohmsgaming.com$ [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.forum.ohmsgaming.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/ohmsgaming\.com\/community\/forum\/" [R=301,L] 
    </IfModule> 

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^outhousemouse.com$ [OR] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.outhousemouse.com$ 
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/ohmsgaming\.com" [R=301,L] 
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Ok well I changed the RewriteRule to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/ohmsgaming\.com\/community\/forum\/$ [R=301,L] and it seems to work again, so this is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape the RewriteRule values.  That might be your problem.

Example:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://ohmsgaming.com/community/forum/ [R=301,L]
```

When in doubt, turn on rewrite logging:

```
RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/MYDOMAIN_rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 5
```

This log can be viewed using `tail -f /path/to/log`, then reload the page.  It will clearly list the processing going on.

**Edit**

I just noticed that the conditions are *not* escaped, they should look like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.ohmsgaming\.com$
```

Comment: OK I am noob to these fucntions but what is escape the values mean

Comment: Ok rewrite log code is giving 500 errors, and yes I changed the path in the first line of code.

Comment: I just made another note, about escaping the URLs.  Beyond that, can you post the specific error you are getting?  It's usually a *little* useful.

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@ohmsgaming.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: OK, that's the information sent to the user, but it is not the information for the rewrite log.  The rewrite log usually looks like a normal webserver log, and lists the process it went through.  Are you sure that your server doesn't have a different misconfiguration?

Comment: @Tempus35 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1992/discussion-between-overzealous-and-tempus35)

Comment: Changed to this and it seems to work, with this: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/ohmsgaming\.com\/community\/forum\/$1 [R=301,L]